# Visual Studio 2008 Prof. SP1 don't catch WinForm designer exception

Tags: visual-studio-2008, error-handling, crash, windows-forms-designer

I have search the whole forums and websites but I found no real solution for my problem.

The problem I have is that my VS2008 (Sp1) don't catch the exception from designer instead of its crash. Always when I want to see my Form in designer view my VS crash see as follow:

[image: VS2008 Crash]

I ask my colleague if his VS2008 (same Version as mine) behave like my VS2008. He  open the same project and get a correct error message instead of crash, see as follow:

[image: VS2008 Error Message]

Why he get a error message but not I, I don't understand this. I have check all his configuration and what he installed and all was the same. What I'm missing why I don't get a error message?

My attempts:

- Reinstalling VS2008 + SP1 + Windows updates
- Clear my project solution
- Reinstalling .Net Framework Versions.
- Importing the configuration from my colleague
- Check installed .net Framework versions from my colleague

I don't know why I don't get a error message, what I'm missing, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just a simple bug in your Form class, it caused a StackOverflowException.  So powerful that they named a popular programmer's web site after it.  Your colleague just didn't get that far, you didn't give him all the code.  Google "windows forms debug design-time exceptions" to learn how to debug it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I know that the form cause a StackOverflowException but why my VS crash? I mean VS should be able to catch a StackOverflowException or not? My colleague use the exact code as mine, we use the same source (SVN base). That's way I don't understand why his VS2008 is able to handle the StackOverflowException but not mine.  I mean how should I know the error in my form when I don't get a proper Error Message?

Comment: SOE is notorious for causing immediate program termination without a way to catch the exception.  If that happens inside VS, like it does when the code runs in the designer, then that will instantly terminate VS.  Why your colleague doesn't have the IncForm class yet is unclear, maybe he just forgot to compile it.  Once he does, it is no doubt going to bomb the same way.  Just focus on finding the bug instead of fretting over your colleague's repro.   Non-zero odds that it is broken property in IncForm that caused it btw, code in a base class runs at design-time.

Comment: Ok, thanks you are right searching for the bug make more sense instead to find out why I don't get error message. I will check now the property.

Comment: I don't understand the error message. I have check the base form but did not find something suspicious. Have someone another idea what cause this error?